# Constrained LP in two variables

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Suppose we have the following constrained LP
$$\max_{y} \min_x c^Tx  $$
$$\text{s.t} \qquad x \geq a + b y^T x $$

Since now $y$ just appears in constraint, can we change the above LP somehow such that the optimization over $y$ appears only in constraints?

Comment: What do you mean "such that the optimization over $y$ appears only in constraints"? Already in your formulation, $y$ appears only in the constraints. Also: (1) This is not an LP (because of the $\max \min$), and (2) it is not in two variables ($x$ and $y$ appear to be vectors).

Comment: This isn't an LP, but for each fixed y you have an LP where you could obtain the range of possible values of x and the optimal value of $c^{T}x$.  You can could then try to optimize with respect to $y$.

Comment: BrianBorchers thats right. This is a LP for a given $y$. But now if lets say $y \in \mathcal{Y}$ where $\mathcal{Y}$ is a convex set. Can I  just solve for finitely many $y$ say the extreme points?